# Problem importing FBX animation from Daz3d

Tags: animation, import, .fbx

So I imported  Daz G3F to blender before. It worked as you can see in the the first model on the left, then I tried again later this month with another model but same G3F, problems occurred.

I tried again with the same file that had been successfully imported but problems continued, either the bone armatures messed up or the model does not attach to the armatures at all ( you can see in the photo from left to right). Could anyone help me to check what is the traceback call means? How come it worked before but now it doesn't? :( I am very new to blender so pardon for my limited knowledge on this. Really appreciate any help right now I have a project to finish this week.

[image]

[image]

Comment: here is the tutorial I followed at the beginning to import the FBX https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRqJSUGr-is&t=13s

Comment: well.. that file path.. Not that I'm sure it's too long for Blender to read it but.. it's better just to avoid that by installing Blender (and programs in general) somewhere else. Btw is that official Blender install? What were the FBX import options? what were the export options? Most likely something changed since last time that you've successfully imported it.

Comment: The FBX import is checked in below:

- import normals
- import animation 
- import user properties
- import enums as strings
- image search 
- automatic bone orientation

I installed the blender file to application (i'm using a mac) is there something else i have to do? sorry again I'm quite new --

Comment: it works perfectly fine when i import G2F model, weird...

Comment: Update the export option from Daz3d is 
- embed textures
- collect textures to folder
- merge clothing into figure skeleton 
- allow degraded skinning 
- allow degraded scaling
- subD information 
- collapse UV tiles

My friend tried to import into C4D, the problem is the armature behaves weirdly too.. so the problem is probably because of Daz3d

Comment: Yes if importing in other programs doesn't work as expected than it is export which should be revised but then it's not Blender related. I'm not familiar with Daz neither with Genesis so it's hard to tell what are there options to export animation correctly. Regarding export options in general maybe this can be useful https://widdershinsstudio.uk/exporting-daz3d-models-or-characters-into-unity-for-animation/.